# Kubernetes apiserver anonymous healthcheck

Tags: kubernetes

When disabling anonymous-auth in kube-apiserver.yaml file afterwards the healthcheck starts failing. How can this be avoided. Kubernetes Cluster runs with self-signed tls certificates.

Comment: Kubernetes version?

Comment: The Kubernetes version is v.1.9.2

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to allow anonymous requests to the apiserver, your options are:

- provide authentication credentials to the component performing the health check
- OR, switch the health check to a TCP ping (not recommended, since it means it would treat any TCP connection as healthy, even when /healthz was returning unhealthy)
- OR, expose an unsecured port and make your health check use that (not recommended, since it exposes an access method that gives full API access via an http port)